# Dynamic array of function pointers without typedef

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I've got this:

```
void (**funcs)();
funcs = new void (*)()[n];
```

And am getting errors about void, parenthesis, etc. What is the right syntax?

I know about vectors but I just want to know how it would be done this way.

Comment: Or better use `std::function` with `std::vector`.

Comment: @jogojapan I've seen that question just before asking this actually--it's just missing the second part, eg. where [n] is (or at least as far as I can decipher).

Comment: You want `funcs = new (void (*[3])());`

Comment: Curious: why don't you want to use a typedef?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you insist on using raw pointers for some reason, or you're just curious, the syntax is:

```
void (**funcs)() = new (void(*[100])());
```

But seriously, just use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<void(*)()> vec;
```

Comment: I don't think this is answering the OP's question.

Comment: I do have a reason, but thank you for giving the alternate method too for when I'll feel less masochistic.